# combine result in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$query = 
         "
         SELECT
           detail_firstN AS firstname,
           detail_lastN AS lastname
         FROM users
         WHERE
           users_id = :users_id
         ";
```

The result will be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Doe
)
```

Is there any way in MySQL that I can combine the result for me to have only this output?

```
Array
(
    [name] => John Doe
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `CONCAT`

```
SELECT CONCAT(detail_firstN, ' ', detail_lastN) AS Name
FROM   users
WHERE  users_id = :users_id
```

- [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

or `CONCAT_WS`

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', detail_firstN, detail_lastN) AS Name
FROM   users
WHERE  users_id = :users_id
```

- [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

**UPDATE 1**

- [See SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8b73/1)

Comment: Thanks for this, it's just that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?PHP

function combine_result($array,$out_key = "name") // Deafult output key is [name]
{
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        $vals = array_values($array);
        $out  = implode(" ",$vals);
        return array($out_key=>$out);
    }
}


$array = array(
                "firstname" => "John",
                "lastname" => "Doe" );


print_r(combine_result($array)); // Array ( [name] => John Doe )


?>
```

Comment: why do you need to do this in PHP when you can do it directly on the MySQL server?

Comment: Thanks for this, however as I stated, I need to do the work via MySQL.